# Turn off Duplicate Rules in Scratch Org

Tags: duplicate-matching-rule, circleci

I am doing CI builds using CircleCI and scratch orgs.  My scratch org definition is here:

```
{
    "orgName": "CircleCI",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["Communities"],
    "settings": {
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": true
        }
    }
}
```

My unit tests are failing because the default duplicate rules are activated by default.  They need to be deactivated for my tests to run without error as they are not used with my package.

Is there any way to deactivate duplicate rules when creating the scratch org during CI builds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest route is to just capture the metadata to deactivate these rules:

1. Build a scratch org locally.
2. Manually deactivate the out-of-the-box Duplicate Rules in the org.
3. Capture the modified metadata to source. Put it in a separate package directory from your main application.
4. In CI, script deployment of this metadata prior to deploying your app.

---

If you use [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (disclaimer: my team's free and open source product), you can use the out-of-the-box [`set_duplicate_rule_status`](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#set-duplicate-rule-status) task in your automation, which will inspect the org and turn off the duplicate rules for you without needing to store metadata.

---

These approaches work if you are building an org, or a first-generation managed package. If you are building a second-generation managed package, you cannot intervene in the build org imperatively. You would need to use the [unpackaged metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm) feature to deploy captured Duplicate Rule metadata rather than scripting in step (4).

Comment: Excellent, David!  Thank you!